# How would I plot this function for all values of X,Y?

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

I have this function which I wish to plot:
$y=b(a-x)^{8/25}$

I have the values for $x,y$ as part of a data set, with thousands of values. This is in a file.  What i have found is that $x$ is between 0 and 5 and $y$ is between 0 and 1.

I tried rearranging the equation to solve for $a$ and $b$, but I am still not sure what to do with that information

[image]

[image]

My main problems are that I dont know how to plot $a,b$ in a single graph that represents all values in the $x,y$ range. A secondary problem might be that I don't know how to write the equation properly, given what I am trying to do.
And a tertiary concern is that I am also unsure how to get this into a graphing program. Insights are welcome.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Will your graph plot $x$ against $y$ or $a$ against $b$? If you are graphing $x$ vs. $y$, and you have values of $x$ and $y$, why don't you just graph them and ignore $a$ and $b$? Or are you trying to find $a$ and $b$? Are your values of $x$ and $y$ exact for a given $a$ and $b$? And so on. Please clarify: this is a hopeless mess now.

Comment: I have X,Y and Im trying to find A,B.

Comment: OK, what about all my other questions? Note that my question "Are your values of $x$ and $y$ exact for a given $a$ and $b$?" refers to the best-fit idea given by @RobertIsrael. Is that what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that what you're really trying to do is find $a$ and $b$ that best fit  the equation $y = b (a-x)^{8/25}$, and further that "best fit" is in the least squares sense, i.e. you want to minimize
$$ \sum_i (y_i - b(a-x_i)^{8/25})^2$$
where $(x_i, y_i)$ are your data points.  This is a [non-linear least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-linear_least_squareshttp://) problem, so it is not easy, but methods are available on various software systems (Matlab, Maple, Sage, etc.).

Comment: Do those methods have names?

Comment: Gauss-Newton, Levenberg-Marquardt, Sequential Quadratic Programming.